# Why am I getting this error when using Material UI?

Tags: javascript, material-ui, icons, npm-install

I used `npm install @mui/material` and `npm install @mui/icons-material` right after to import a search icon. my code looks like this

```
import {Search} from "@mui/icons-material";
```

However, when I write it in my code as `<Search />` I get this error.

[image]

What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The package you are trying to use is a set of react components. In other words, you can't use it without React. Have a look at [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mui/icons-material).

Comment: @speedDaemon I'm using react and I have already done what you sent me in the beginning. It now says it's compiled successfully but the browser does not output anything it's just a blank screen.